# Equating volume of sphere and cylinder

Tags: geometry, volume

A right circular cylindrical tank having a height of 2 feet and perimeter of the base as 22 feet was filled with water up to 80% of its actual capacity. What is the minimum number of lead balls each having radius of 0.10 feet, that should be dropped into the tank so as to increase the volume to at least 90%?

- 800
- 900
- 919
- 1838
- 2757

Since the % increase is 10, the volume which should be filled with lead balls is 10 % of the cylindrical volume. 
(volume of sphere)*(no of spheres) = 10%(volume of cylinder)

On equating, I get ans in decimals.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @TheIntegrator answer is supposed to be 1838

Comment: i didnt know it was the options in the earlier edit. looks better now

Comment: We can't see where you are going wrong if you don't show your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perimeter of the base is $22= 2\pi r_c\implies r_c = \dfrac{11}{\pi}$

now with the actual problem ;

$n\times \dfrac43\pi r_s^3 = \dfrac{10}{100}\pi r_c^2h $

$n \cdot \dfrac43 \cdot (0.1)^3 = (0.1)\cdot (\dfrac{11}{\pi})^2\cdot 2$

$n = \dfrac{121\cdot 3}{2\cdot \pi^2\cdot 0.01}$

$n = 1838.979483$

The key word in the answer is "minimum" and "atleast 90%". So we take the lower bound of the answer which is $1838$

Comment: Oh thank you so much for this!
Understood :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is 1837.70 which is rounding off to near integer 1838.

Comment: The key words are "minimum number" and "at least." You can only put a non-negative integer number of balls in the tank. The result here shows that $1838$ balls will satisfy the "at least 90%" criterion, and indeed that will give you more volume than you need, but $1837$ balls is not enough.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now!